# How to set dialog position using jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Yes, I know there were similar questions - they did not answer.  I also know that jQuery is a fairly old framework - but that's not the point.

I am writing an application in which I use jQuery UI dialog boxes as tool windows. The application saves their current position in cookies when they are closed. This is done so that when you open the application, the windows are restored to their previous positions.

However, I cannot set this position back.

I am trying to use the `position` function for this as follows:

Befor I make dialog, I get information about stored position from cookies

```
// I get only "pointer" to it
dlg=$('#dlg-Tiles');

// The first parameter is the window ID in the settings, the second is 
// the default parameters for the window position, if there was no 
// entry in the configuration
let windowCfg=getWindowConfig(dlg,{
            position:{my:"left top", at:"left+100 top+50", of: "#viewport"},
            width:200,
            height:450});
```

The result of this function is an object with the following structure:

```
{
    position:{
        my:"top left",
        at:"top+55 left+550", // values 55 and 550 are examples :)
        of:"#viewport"
    },
    width:200,
    height:500
}
```

In short, I am using the option of assigning an offset for the `at` parameter.

Next, I make a dialog:

```
dlg.dialog({
    appendTo: '#viewport',
    autoOpen:false,
    position: windowCfg.position,
    width: windowCfg.width,
    height: windowCfg.height,
    resizable: true,
    closeOnEscape: false        .
})
```

When the dialog window is opened (calling `dlg.dialog('open')` ), its position is set by default from jQuery UI (`{my:"center center", at:"center center", ...}`), not from the parameter I passed when creating the dialog window.

My question is. Why doesn't it work?

For example, let me say that the following code runs without a problem:

```
dlg=$('#dlg-Tiles')

dlg.dialog({
   appendTo:'#viewport',
   autoOpen:false,
   position: {my:'left top', at:'left+20 top+20', of:'#viewport'},
   resizable:true,
   closeOnEscape: false})

dlg.dialog('open');
```

The window is opened relative to its upper left corner, relative to the `#viewport` object to its upper left corner with an offset of 20 to right and 20 down.

Where's the difference? Where is the mistake of my thinking?

Comment: Your code works for me - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/3s2405fn/). Only strange things I notice are probably just typos here on SO: 1) Your code swaps parameter order - `left top` and `top left`; 2) Trailing `.` after `closeOnEscape: false`. Are yiou absolutely sure your `getWindowConfig()` function is setting `windowCfg`  correctly? Checked it with `console.dir(windowCfg)`?

Comment: Your guideline for the order parameter `top left` / `left top` was a hit.
I didn't think that the order in this place matters.
Thanks.